# What is reason for using MAX in below code

Tags: sql, max

I tried to delete this MAX but it is not working: `Round(MAX(UnitPrice),2) AS UnitPrice`

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS YEAR,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) as Month,
    ProductId,
    Round(MAX(UnitPrice),2) AS UnitPrice, -- this line
    sum(Quantity) as UnitSold
FROM projectanka.salesproject.sales
Group BY
    YEAR,
    Month,
    ProductId
Order by
    YEAR,
    Month,
    ProductId;
```

Comment: So that it'll show the highest unitprice value from the grouped rows, I imagine. Similar to the sum (but just a different calculation)

Comment: `GROUP BY` means you'll have multiple values of `UnitPrice` per row in the result. `ROUND()` doesn't take multiple values, so `MAX()` is used to provide only the largest to `ROUND()`.